# Running 6 Month Sum for Each Value of an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to calculate a 6 month running sum of "Points" for each badge number. The sum only applies to fields with points greater than 0.

I have been trying to do this using an array and a For statement, but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
Sub TestArray()
'
'
'
' Test Array Macro

    Dim Badges() As Long
    Dim Badge As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Double
    Dim Worksheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim AbsCode As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row


    Set Worksheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Attendance Data") ' Change name of sheet if necessary
    BadgeNo = 1
    AbsCode = 3
    Hours = 5
    Points = 9
    Rules = 10
    test = 15

    ReDim Badges(2 To LastRow, 1 To 1)

    For Each Badge In Badges        
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If Worksheet1.Cells(i, Points).Value > 0 Then
                Worksheet1.Cells(i, test).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheet1.Cells(i, Points).Value)
            Else: Worksheet1.Cells(i, test).Value = 0
            End If
            Next i
    Next Name



End Sub
```

The answer that I'm looking for is in the "6 Month Points" column below.

```
Badge No.   Incident Date   Points  6 Month Points
30004832    1/13/2018       0.5           0.5
30004832    1/27/2018       0.0           0
30004832    4/5/2018        1.0           1.5
30004832    7/19/2018       0.0           0
30004832    7/22/2018       0.5           1.5
30004832    9/22/2018       1.0           2.5
30005505    8/4/2018        0.5           0.5
30005505    12/6/2018       0.5           1
30005914    12/20/2018      0.0           0
30004641    1/18/2018       0.5           0.5
30004641    2/2/2018        0.5           1
30004641    7/17/2018       0.0           0
30004641    10/16/2018      0.0           0
30000503    4/12/2012       0.0           0
30000503    5/3/2012        0.0           0
30000503    6/14/2012       0.0           0
```

Comment: Why vba?  This can be done with a formula.

Comment: It's part of a bigger project that I am creating for someone that doesn't know much about excel. I am hoping to be able to import a data set, sort it and calculate the points all with them just clicking a button or using a shortcut key.